# Is it necessary that chaos monkey can termination only instance which deployed by spinnaker ?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, chaos, spinnaker-halyard

Is it necessary that chaos monkey can termination only instance which deployed by spinnaker ?

If we are using another cloud management platform Rightscale and GCE to deployed the machine and deployed spinnaker only for use the choas monkey to terminate the instances of existing environment. Is it work ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand what it is that you're asking here, but I'm reading your post right, you're asking if you can use Netflix's Chaos Monkey to terminate stuff that's not managed by Spinnaker. Did I get that right?

If so, then the answer is no, Netflix's Chaos Monkey can only work with stuff deployed via Spinnaker. You can see that in [Chaos Monkey's official Github repository](https://github.com/Netflix/chaosmonkey):

> This version of Chaos Monkey is fully integrated with Spinnaker, the continuous delivery platform that we use at Netflix. You must be managing your apps with Spinnaker to use Chaos Monkey to terminate instances.

The way they're using "This version" at the start of that sentence might mean that there's a fork out there that can work with other CD programs. I didn't find anything though...

Comment: Yes Goncalo, You got the exactly question. Can you please suggest another tool/framework which can be use for resiliency testing of application deployed on Google cloud?

Comment: Sorry, I've searched around yet again but couldn't find anything that'd do this out-of-the-box for GCE...